# links doesn't work in admin dashboard and icons also doesn't display

Tags: admin, dashboard

I've installed latest Magento on window but the links doesn't work in admin dashboard and icons also doesn't shown?

I already tried this one:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and replace to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to run :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and then

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```